# How to improve speed of python loop?

Tags: python

I have a large dataframe I need to analyse according to different scenarios, and I'm looking for a method to (easily) speed up the process if possible.

Essentially my code is something like (really, really simplified);

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

dict_x = {}
for x in range(0, 10):
    dict_y = {}
    for y in range(0, 10):
        for i in range(0, len(df)):
            df.loc[i, 'E'] = ((df.loc[i, 'A'] * df.loc[i, 'B']) * x) + y
        dict_y[y] = df
    dict_x[x] = dict_y
```

Due to the number of scenarios it takes a long time to run. Each scenario is independent of the others. Is there a way to improve the speed?  Like enabling python to use multiple cores/analyse multiple scenarios at once, or something else

I had a look at the multiprocessing module, but I could not understand how to apply it. I'm pretty new to Python, so I'm probably missing something basic.

****Edit**: Updated example of code, hopefully that is easier to understand what I am trying to achieve. The actual code is far longer due to the number of sensors and calculations needed on the system, and there's data for every minute in one month.

Comment: please provide an actual working example of your code.

Comment: you can use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: What is your desired output? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Multiprocessing `may` be a solution, but it depends on your actual problem and how reducible it it. We'd need to seem more of it to know for sure.

Comment: Your last iteration of `y` will set `df` to `99` on the first `x` independend of `df`  → `df = (df * 0) + 99`. So can just start from there.

Comment: @Gahan multithreading is of little help in Python (cf https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)  - the right solution here is probably multiprocessing in one way or another.

Comment: Have a look at [`dask`](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/). This is similar to pandas but provides parallel computing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can work on:

Start with, Vectorization: Using numpy library for loop multiplication/addtion and other math operations. This will reduce your time by a factor of 1000(may be greater than that)

The other area you can work on is parallel processing of your data which is independent of each other. See, documentations of multi-threading and multi-processing.